# What is the correct way to draw lines direction by conditional

Tags: d3.js

I have 3 datas with me. each data has different values. using the data `size` I am drawing lines.

my request is, how do I add the condition each of the values to draw the line different way?

for example my case, the second data need to draw from right to left, instead of left to right.

What is the correct way to do this?

```js
var height = 500;
  var width = 500;
  
  var data = [
      {"name":"name1", "size":10, "count":8},
      {"name":"name2", "size":20, "count":20},
      {"name":"name3", "size":30, "count":60}
    ]
  
  var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr({
    width:width,
    height:height
  }).append('g');
  
  var line = svg.selectAll('line')
              .data( data )
              .enter()
              .append('line')
              .style("stroke", "black")
              .attr("x1", function(d){ 10  })
              .attr("y1",  function(d){ return d.size })
              .attr('x2', function(d) { return 0 })
              .attr("y2", function (d){ return d.size })
              .transition()
              .delay(2000)
              .duration(2000)
              .attr("x2", function (d){ return width - d.size })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just insert a check in your drawing function.

```
function(d){ 
  if(d.name === "name2")
    // code to draw right to left
  else
    // code to draw left to right
}
```

or, if you prefer to use the index,

```
function(d, i){
  if(i === 1)
    // code to draw right to left
  else
    // code to draw left to right
}
```

If your logic affects `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, and `y2`, then it might be easier to do everything in a `.each` call:

```
var line = svg.selectAll('line')
          .data( data )
          .enter()
          .append('line')
          .style("stroke", "black")
          .each(function(d, i){
             // custom logic here to decide what's x1, x2, y1, y2
             // based on d and i
             d3.select(this){
               .attr("x1", ...)
               .attr("y1", ...)
               .attr('x2', ...)
               .attr("y2", ...)
               // etc
           });
```

Comment: If you don't mind, I have another question to  you,  in this graph http://plnkr.co/edit/7PNd8BOmyut88X5bavj3?p=preview - how to i prevent to draw the green lines at top and right side? I require only left and bottom.

Comment: can you explain a little bit more? I'm not seeing any green lines in the graph...